# Does bit shift automatically promote chars to int?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I read somewhere that bitwise shift automatically turns the operand into an int. But I'm not sure if that statement should be qualified with "if the operands are of unequal type."

```
char one = 1, bitsInType = 8;
one << (bitsInType - one);
```

Does the default result of the second line result in an int or char?

Comment: @MarkRansom: I do not think that is a good duplicate. That question addresses the fact that the usual arithmetic conversions are not performed. This question addresses the fact that the integer promotions are performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result type is `int` in normal C implementations.<sup>1</sup>

Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.5.7, “The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is the that of the promoted left operand.”

Per 6.3.1.1 2, the integer promotions are, for objects or expressions of integer type with rank less than or equal to the rank of **int** and **unsigned int**: “If an **int** can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an **int**; otherwise, it is converted to an **unsigned int**.”

---

<sup>1</sup>There has been discussion elsewhere in Stack Overflow from which it seems that a bizarre C implementation could have a `char` of the same width as `int`, which leads to some unusual behavior.

Answer (score 1):

C11 Standard, section 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators, states:

The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
that of the promoted left operand.

This means that the values are converted to `int` and then the operation is performed; the result of your expression is `int`.