# shifting an unsigned char by more than 8 bits

Tags: c, endianness, unsigned-char

I'm a bit troubled by this code:

```
typedef struct _slink{
    struct _slink* next;
    char type;
    void* data;
}
```

assuming what this describes is a link in a file, where data is 4bytes long representing either an address or an integer(depending on the type of the link)

Now I'm looking at reformatting numbers in the file from little-endian to big-endian, and so what I wanna do is change the order of the bytes before writing back to the file, i.e.
for `0x01020304`, I wanna convert it to `0x04030201` so when I write it back, its little endian representation is gonna look like the big endian representation of `0x01020304`, I do that by multiplying the `i'th` byte by `2^8*(3-i)`, where `i` is between 0 and 3. Now this is one way it was implemented, and what troubles me here is that this is shifting bytes by more than 8 bits.. (L is of type _slink*)

```
int data = ((unsigned char*)&L->data)[0]<<24) + ((unsigned char*)&L->data)[1]<<16) + 
                    ((unsigned char*)&L->data)[2]<<8) + ((unsigned char*)&L->data)[3]<<0)
```

Can anyone please explain why this actually works? without having explicitly cast these bytes to integers to begin with(since they're only 1 bytes but are shifted by up to 24 bits)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, the code has a bug. `(unsigned char*)&L->data)[0]` is an `unsigned char`. With an 8-bit `unsigned char` and a 32-bit `int`, it will be automatically promoted to `int`. Then `<<24` shifts the value 24 bits. If the high bit (7) of the `unsigned char` is set, it is shifted into the high bit (31) of the `int`. This overflows the signed `int`, and then the behavior is not defined by the C standard. To fix this, `(unsigned char*)&L->data)[0]` should be cast to `unsigned int` before `<<24`.

Comment: Could you just use the functions from the `htonl` family? https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does bit shift automatically promote chars to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370197/does-bit-shift-automatically-promote-chars-to-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any integer type smaller than `int` is **promoted** to type `int` when used in an expression.

So the shift is actually applied to an expression of type `int` instead of type `char`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please explain why this actually works?

The shift does not occur as an `unsigned char` but as a type promoted to an  `int`<sup>1</sup>. [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62666337/2410359).

Reasons why code still has issues.

**32-bit `int`**

Shifting a `int` 1 into the the sign's place is *undefined behavior* UB.  See also [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666302/shifting-an-unsigned-char-by-more-than-8-bits/62666617#comment110821368_62666302).

```
((unsigned char*)&L->data)[0]<<24)  // UB
```

**16-bit `int`**

Shifting by the bit width or more is insufficient precision even if the type was `unsigned`.  As `int` it is UB like above. Perhaps then OP would have only wanted a 2-byte endian swap?

**Alternative**

```
const uint8_t *p = &L->data;
uint32_t data = (uint32_t)p[0] << 24 | (uint32_t)p[1] << 16 | //
    (uint32_t)p[2] << 8 | (uint32_t)p[3] << 0;
```

**For the pedantic**

Had `int` used non-2's complement, the addition of a negative value from `((unsigned char*)&L->data)[0]<<24)` would have messed up the data pattern.  Endian manipulations are best done using *unsigned* types.

---

> from little-endian to big-endian

This code does not swap between those 2 endians.  It is a big endian to native endian swap.  When this code is run on a 32-bit `unsigned` little endian machine, it is effectively a big/little swap.  On a 32-bit `unsigned` big endian machine, it could have been a no-op.

---

<sup>1</sup> ... or posibly an `unsigned` on select platforms where `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`.